# How to select rows in parent table based on a value in child table

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, inner-join

Consider the following tables, what would be an efficient query to return 1 row for each order that has at least 1 child row with a specific warehouse code? I am using SQL Server 2016.

```
Table: Orders
OrderNo OrderDt    Status Type
------- ---------- ------ --------
200123  11/20/2020 NEW    SHIPPING
200124  11/21/2020 NEW    IN-STORE
200125  11/21/2020 NEW    SHIPPING
```

```
Table: OrderItems
OrderNo ItemCode Warehouse
------- -------- ---------
200123  Item1    10
200124  Item1    10
200124  Item2    20
200125  Item2    20
```

If I query for Warehouse 10:

```
OrderNo OrderDt    Status Type
------- ---------- ------ --------
200123 11/20/2020  NEW    SHIPPING
200124 11/21/2020  NEW    IN-STORE
```

If I query for Warehouse 20:

```
OrderNo OrderDt    Status Type
------- ---------- ------ --------
200124  11/21/2020 NEW    IN-STORE
200125  11/21/2020 NEW    SHIPPING
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that when you say "When I query for Warehouse X" you are running individual queries for a single warehouse, just a simple `INNER JOIN` and a `WHERE` clause should do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.OrderNo, o.OrderDt, o.Status, o.Type
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN OrderItems oi ON o.OrderNo = oi.OrderNo
WHERE Warehouse = 10;

SELECT DISTINCT o.OrderNo, o.OrderDt, o.Status, o.Type
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN OrderItems oi ON o.OrderNo = oi.OrderNo
WHERE Warehouse = 20;
```

If you want to have everything in one result set add `ItemCode` and `Warehouse` to the query and leave out the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT
    o.OrderNo,
    o.OrderDt,
    o.Status,
    o.Type,
    oi.ItemCode,
    oi.Warehouse
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN OrderItems oi ON o.OrderNo = oi.OrderNo;
```

Comment: Thanks! It was the DISTINCT keyword that was escaping me as I thought about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where exists (
    select 1 
    from orderitems oi 
    where oi.orderno = o.orderno and oi.warehouse = 10
)
```

For performance with this query, consider an index on `orderitems(orderno, warehouse)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query we filter out the warehouse prior joining the tables:

```
select distinct o.orderNo, o.OrderDt, o.Status, o.Type from orders o, (select orderNo, Warehouse from orderitems 
where warehouse = ##) o1
on o1.orderNo = o.orderNo
```

Comment: Evolve! No one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). And your old-style join will throw an error because you tried to use both join techniques.